# animation can't begin in scrollview in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, windows-phone-8, blend

I want to implement an effect like this:
there is a 80*80 scrollview,and i put a 160*80 pic in it
1s:the pic left/up in the scrollview,2s:the pic right/up in the scrollview
rolling as a transition process

my code:
**xaml**

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="my_combo_pic">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="80"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="my_combo_pic">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>


...
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="my_combo" Tap="MyCombolIconTapped" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="80" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="80">
                    <Image x:Name="my_combo_pic" Stretch="Fill" Source="/Images/my_combo_icon.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="160" Width="80">
                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform/>
                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                    </Image>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
```

**cs**

```
    Storyboard1.Begin();
```

in the **Loaded**

But,i find that the animation don't work even it works well in the **expression blend**
So,can u help me find out what reason it is???
Or give me another way to implement this
thank U!!!
Any Advice will be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your `ScrollViewer` content within a `Grid` like so:

```
<ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            <Image x:Name="my_combo_pic" Stretch="Fill" Source="/Images/my_combo_icon.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="160" Width="266">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform />
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
        </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The problem here is that the animation system is getting a little confused since the `ScrollViewer` only has an `Image` in it which isn't a container in itself, so it figures that there is no where to animate (since it's not relative to anything).

Comment: but there is a problem,if i change the scrollview to grid,the rolling object will above the container,and i'll see the whole 160*80 rolling object above the container.

Comment: i just want to let the rolling object in the container,and I only see 80*80

Comment: what puzzle me most is that when i use a move-position animation,the moving object seems always on the surface,above all the container,i don't know where my fault is

Comment: I wasn't advocating replacing the `ScrollViewer`. Put the `Grid` above inside the  `ScrollViewer`.